What shear matrix leaves the line y=x invariant in this diagram?
In the Figure below I would like to shear the triangle OAB to OAC so that the area of the triangle is the same, but I can't work out the transformation matrix required. The small squares have sides $a=\sqrt{5}$, the medium one $b=\sqrt{20}$ and the big one $d^2$ (for any reasonable $d > b$, it shouldn't matter the precise value), then I tried looking for the parameters $\lambda$ and $\mu$ in
$$
\boldsymbol{M} = \pmatrix{1+\lambda\mu & \lambda\\ \mu & 1}
$$
that would take point $B = (b+d, d-b)$ to $C = (b, -b)$ [taking the origin to be at $O$], and indeed found a matrix that would do that: $\lambda = d/b, \mu = -d/(b+d)$. But the problem is that it doesn't leave the line segment $OA$ invariant, which I thought it would do since $OA$ is parallel to $BC$. What am I doing wrong?


That matrix on Wikipedia is NOT the matrix for a general shear. See the answers here instead: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2229844/general-form-of-a-shear-map

$\def\ed{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}$
Hint
A shear leaving the line $\ AO\ $ fixed will translate  any point not on $\ AO\ $ along a line parallel to $\ OA\ $ by an amount proportional to its distance from $\ OA\ $.  Since the distance of $\ B\ $ from $\ OA\ $ is  $\ |OC|=2\sqrt{10}\ ,$ and the distance you want to move it is $\ d\sqrt{2}\ ,$ the constant of proportionality is $\ \frac{d\sqrt{2}}{2\sqrt{10}}=\frac{d}{\sqrt{20}}\ .$  Thus, if $\ u\ed \pmatrix{\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}\\\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}}\ $ and $\ v\ed \pmatrix{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}}\ $ are the unit vectors along, and perpendicular to, respectively, the direction in which you want to translate $\ B\ ,$ then the shear transformation $\ S\ $ you want is given by
\begin{align}
S(\rho u+\lambda v)&=\rho u+\lambda v+\frac{d\lambda}{\sqrt{20}}u\\
&=\left(\rho+\frac{d\lambda}{\sqrt{20}}\right)u+\lambda v\ ,
\end{align}
from which its matrix with respect to the basis $\ u,v\ $ can be read off directly. Recovering its matrix with respect to the standard basis is then a standard exercise in linear algebra
